# Can a CMYK PDF be hacked or converted to duotone?

Tags: color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [duotone PDF files with lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45264/duotone-pdf-files-with-lualatex)

I have CMYK PDF files compiled with `lualatex`, but the publisher requires duotone.

I've seen some [cool tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17757/is-it-possible-to-use-spot-colors-in-tikz-graphics) about manipulating the colour channels and separating them.

Perhaps something like this can be used to hack a CMYK file and create a duotone file? Or colour separated files that the publisher might be able to use?

Or perhaps this is technically not feasible.